# JavaScript RegExp objects

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to write a simple Markdown parser in JavaScript. Therefore I want to check for the `[link content][link id]` syntax. I use the following code:

```
data = data.replace( /\[(.*?)\][ ]*\[([0-9]+)\]/g, '<a href="$2">$1</a>' );
```

It works well, but now I want to do this with a RegExp object. So I set up the following bit of code:

```
var r = new RegExp( '\[(.*?)\][ ]*\[([0-9]+)\]', 'g' );
data = data.replace( r, '<a href="$2">$1</a>' );
```

But it doesn't work. It even says that my regular expression (which works since the first example does a good job) is invalid:

> unmatched ) in regular expression

I think it must have to do with some RegExp-object peculiarities I am not aware of.
What am I doing wrong and how can the problem be solved?

Comment: On a side note you might find it useful to run your JavaScript regular expressions through an online tester (http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm).

Comment: Thanks, seems to be a great tool. I used this (http://regexp-evaluator.de/evaluator/) PHP-ish evaluator. Maybe a JS-ish is better when scripting in JS :)

Comment: `data.replace(/foo/g, 'bar')` and `data.replace(new RegExp('/foo', 'g'), 'bar')` are the same thing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the first argument of the RegExp constructor is a string, not a pattern literal, you have to escape the backslashes, since you want literal backslashes in the pattern:

```
var r = new RegExp( '\\[(.*?)\\][ ]*\\[([0-9]+)\\]', 'g' );
```

Comment: Uhm.. didn't think about those string issues. Now it's obvious. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the pattern's backslash problem, this:

```
data = data.replace( r, '<a href="$2">$1</a>' );
```

could be dangerous. I'll assume you've already taken care of the HTML-escaping, so I won't be able to do this:

```
[<script>stealCookies()</script>][http://oops.example.com/]
[hover me][http://hello" onmouseover="stealCookies()]
```

but you'll still need to check the URL is a known-good scheme so I can't do this:

```
[click me][javascript:stealCookies()]
```

You'll probably want to use the String.replace(r, func) variant of the method, and include validation in your replacement-making 'func'.

Answer (score 0):

```
var r = /\[(.*?)\][ ]*\[([0-9]+)\]/g;
data = data.replace( r, '<a href="$2">$1</a>' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Double escape you backslashes:

```
var r = new RegExp( '\\[(.*?)\\][ ]*\[([0-9]+)\\]', 'g' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to double escape:

```
var r = new RegExp( '\\[(.*?)\\][ ]*\\[([0-9]+)\\]', 'g' )
```