# buillding regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to replace specific amount of white-spaces from a String at the beginning and i can use

```
replace(/^\s{2}/g,"");
```

and it works .but 2 should be changed according to a value of a variable .so i need to construct a `new RegExp()`

so i used

```
var lead=2;
var regex = new RegExp("\^\\s{" + lead + "}//g");
alert("regex  "+regex);
```

real output

```
 /^\s{2}\/\/g/
```

expected output

```
/^\s{2}/g
```

could you help me to fix this problem.tnx

Comment: @nhahtdh I don't think this question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript Even the answers on this question will not help to solve this problem

Comment: yes it didn't .i'm not asking how to use variables in regex

Comment: @Tushar: Better dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516917/javascript-regexp-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the param to `RegExp` is the regex, you don't need the `/` delimiters. Use the flags as the second parameter to the `RegEx()` constructor.

```
var regex = new RegExp("^\\s{" + lead + "}", 'g');
```

Example:

```js
var lead = 2;
var regex = new RegExp("^\\s{" + lead + "}", 'gmi');

alert(regex);

var str = '  Say My Name';
alert(str.replace(regex, ''));
```

Comment: one more problem .can i pass 2 flags ?i tried  `new RegExp("^\\s{" + lead + "}", 'g','m');` but shows only one flag

Answer (score 1):

```
new RegExp("^\\s{" + lead + "}", "g");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
"\^\\s{" + lead + "}\/g"
```

instead of

```
"\^\\s{" + lead + "}//g"
```

I think you wanted to escape the "/", but you accidently used "/" instead of "\".

Comment: tnx for ur responce but this gives me `/^\s{2}\/g/`