# How to kill the tabindex="*" with regex and replace all in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to kill the tabindex="*" with regex and replace all in Javascript.

```js
var temp = '<div class="form-group pt-4"><h4><label for="headline_2">[headline]</label><input class="form-control " id="headline_2" name="headline" placeholder="[headlineplh]" tabindex="11" type="text" value=""></h4></div><div class="form-group pt-4"><label for="description_2">[description]</label><input class="form-control " id="description_2" name="description" placeholder="[descriptionplh]" tabindex="12" type="text" value=""></div><div class="form-group pt-4"><label for="order_2">[order]</label><input class="form-control " id="order_2" name="order" placeholder="[orderplh]" tabindex="13" type="number" min="1" max="20" value="1"></div>';

document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = replaceAll(temp, new RegExp("tabindex=\"(\d)*\"", "i"), "");

function replaceAll(string, search, replace) {
  return string.split(search).join(replace);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="p"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript RegExp objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516917/javascript-regexp-objects)

Answer (score 0):

**The reason why it didn't work is because when the characters "\d" are in a string it means a completely different thing than when it's inside a regex.**

That means that `new RegExp('\d')` is different from `new RegExp(/\d/)`


So to fix it you need to escape the backslash, the way do that is by placing another backslash behind it.

In your case you should do: `new RegExp("tabindex=\"(\\d)*\"", "i"), "");`
This will work because I replaced the metacharacter `\d` with `\\d` since it's inside of a string